# how to add widgets "form-control" in django-money

Tags: django, django-templates

how to add widgets in django field for currency and currency code ?
i want to add class "form control" in that field.

[image: django-money in templates]

**templates.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="jumlahUsulanDana">Jumlah Usulan Dana</label>
        {{form.jumlah_dana_usulan}}
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
class Meta:
    model           = UserUsulan
    exclude         = ['status_usulan' ,'jumlah_dana_disetujui', 
   'keterangan_operator', 'com_reviewer_1', 'com_reviewer_2' ]
    widgets = {'jumlah_dana_usulan'        : forms.TextInput({'class' : 
                'form-control', 'id' : 'jumlahUsulanDana', 'placeholder' 
                : 'Jumlah Usulan Dana'}),
              }
```

**EDIT**

If Used attrs in forms.py, any idea ?
[image: Used attrs]

models.py

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class UserUsulan(models.Model):
     ...
     jumlah_dana_usulan          = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='IDR')
     ...
```

Comment: Can you add you model here.

Comment: Also share your settings the `CURRENCY_CHOICES` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are using the django-money library [link here](https://pypi.org/project/django-money/0.11.4/). This library uses a multiwidget for this component see [here](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/blob/main/djmoney/forms/widgets.py) what I can recomend you is just customize the main widget

Do the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django-money.forms.widgets import MoneyWidget


class Meta:
    # ... Your actually code.
    widgets = {
        'jumlah_dana_usulan': MoneyWidget(
            amount_widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-class'}),
            currency_widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                    'class':'form-control',
                    'placeholder':'Jumlah Usulan Dana',
                    'id' : 'jumlahUsulanDana',
                },
                choices=settings.CURRENCY_CHOICES,
            ),
        ),
        # ... Here more widget fields
    }
```

The main point in here is that you have to explore how the base widget is working and try to change the widget of that Multiwidget passing through the constructor.

Comment: Thats worked, but its not solved my problem. Because the field just show one field and value in array. like this [None, 'IDR'] . I want show two field currency and currency code. Like the pictures on the top.
I will edit, this question and upload a new picture if i used your code.

Comment: Please add your model to the question @RahmatSaudiAlFathirAs

Comment: Sure, I'm already edit the post @allexiusw

Comment: @RahmatSaudiAlFathirAs see the changes this really close to what you are looking form just what you have to do is custom it according to your data, some imports can not be exactly imported please check it.